# Как достать из json содержимое?

Tags: javascript, json

Необходим скрипт на javaScript который достаёт из json - svg который в нём спрятан.

```
 {"pages":
    [
        {"id":"page1","class":"art active","type":"box","objHtml":
            {"width":"380px","width_page":380,"height":"380px","left":"770px","fon_color":"transparent"},
            "boxes":[{"id":"box1","type":"style","objHtml":{},"insideBox":"","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                {"id":"box2","type":"figure","objHtml":
                    {"zIndex":"2","height":"160px","top":"60px","left":"110px","fon_color":"transparent","border_width":0,"width":"160px","width_page":160,"svg_fon":"#f44336","svg_border_width":"0","svg_border_color":"#000000","svg_gradient":false,"svg_image":false},
                    "insideBox":"<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?-->\n<!-- Round  -->\n<svg viewBox=\"0 0 200 200\" xmlns=\"https://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:svg=\"https://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"160\"><defs></defs>\n\t\t<g stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#f44336\">\n\t\t\t<circle cx=\"100\" cy=\"100\" r=\"94\"></circle>\n\t\t</g>\n</svg>\n","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box3","type":"line","objHtml":{"line_width":6,"line_color":"#000000","line_style":"solid","zIndex":"7","height":"auto","top":"110px","left":"-53px","rotate":15,"width":"285px","width_page":285},"insideBox":"<hr style=\"border-top: 6px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; height: 0px;\">","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box4","type":"line","objHtml":{"line_width":6,"line_color":"#000000","line_style":"solid","zIndex":"1","height":"auto","width":"342px","width_page":342,"top":"75px","left":"-44px","rotate":20},"insideBox":"<hr style=\"border-top: 6px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; height: 0px;\">","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box5","type":"text","objHtml":{"zIndex":"8","height":"auto","width":"360px","width_page":360,"top":"200px","left":"10px","letterSpacing":"7px"},"insideBox":"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-size: 100px; font-weight: 600; color: rgb(33, 33, 33); font-family: \"Didact Gothic\";\">СУШИ</span></p>","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""},
                    {"id":"box6","type":"text","objHtml":{"zIndex":"9","height":"auto","width":"360px","width_page":360,"top":"310px","left":"10px"},"insideBox":"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"font-family: \"Didact Gothic\";\">Ресторан японской и паназиатской кухни</span></p>","loaded":false,"fix":false,"gClass":""}]}]}
```

Comment: Думаю быстрее будет, все таки попробовать самому)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция - только подай массив =)

```
function find_svg_figure(_pages) {
  for (let i in _pages) {
    for (let j in _pages[i]) {
      if (typeof _pages[i][j] === "object") {
        for (let k in _pages[i][j]) {
          if (typeof _pages[i][j][k] === "object" && _pages[i][j][k].type === 'figure') {
            console.log('JSON: ',_pages[i][j][k]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас json в виде строки, то делаем так:

```
object_item = JSON.parse(json_item);
```

И далее с object_item работаем как с объектом.

Comment: Спасибо вам!)))